# 'wp core install' loading never ends

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, wp-cli

I'm trying to build a wordpress project using wp-cli. I'm at the step of running: `wp core install --url=<your-site-url> --title=<your-site-title> --admin_user=<admin-username> --admin_password=<admin-password> --admin_email=<admin-email>`

However, after hit enter, it runs but the loading never ends. It stops at: Looking for UTF-16 (LE) BOM (0.031s)

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wp-cli has a --debug flag that can provide more detailed output. Running your command with this flag may help identify the problem.

```
wp --debug core install --url=<your-site-url> --title=<your-site-title> --admin_user=<admin-username> --admin_password=<admin-password> --admin_email=<admin-email>
```

Remember to replace your-site-url, your-site-title with your actual details.